# SQL: 3 self-joins and then join them together

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, join

I have 2 tables to join in a specific way.  I think my query is right, but not sure.

```
select t1.userID, t3.Answer Unit, t5.Answer Demo  
FROM    
    table1 t1  
    inner join (select * from table2) t3 ON t1.userID = t3.userID   
    inner join (select * from table2) t5 ON t1.userID = t5.userID  
where  
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 t2 WHERE t2.userID = t1.userID AND t2.date > t1.date)  
    and NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 t4 WHERE t4.userID = t3.userID and t4.counter > t3.counter)  
    and NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 t6 WHERE t6.userID = t5.userID and t6.counter > t5.counter)  
    and t1.date_submitted >'1/1/2009'  
    and t3.question = Unit  
    and t5.question = Demo  
order by  
    t1.userID
```

From table1 I want distinct userID where date > 1/1/2009

```
table1      
userID    Date
1         1/2/2009  
1         1/2/2009  
2         1/2/2009  
3         1/2/2009  
4         1/1/2008
```

So The result I want from table1 should be this:

```
userID  
1  
2  
3
```

I then want to join this on userID with table2, which looks like this:

```
table2 
userID    question   answer   counter
1         Unit       A        1
1         Demo       x        1
1         Prod       100      1
2         Unit       B        1
2         Demo       Y        1
3         Prod       100      1
4         Unit       A        1
1         Unit       B        2
1         Demo       x        2
1         Prod       100      2
2         Unit       B        2
2         Demo       Z        2
3         Prod       100      2
4         Unit       A        2
```

I want to join table1 with table2 with this result:

```
userID    Unit    Demo
1         B       X
2         B       Z
```

In other words,
select distinct userID from table2 where question = Unit for the highest counter
and then
select distinct userID from table2 where question = Demo for the highest counter.

I think what I've done is 3 self-joins then joined those 3 together.

Do you think it's right?

Comment: "Do you think it's right?" - Did it give the right answer when you ran it?

Comment: I think it's giving me the right answer, I was just wondering if you could see anything wrong with it.  We're in SQL 2005.  Thanks

Comment: My query is definitely not right. Still having trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  du.userID, unit.answer, demo.answer
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT userID
        FROM    table1
        WHERE   date > '1/1/2009'
        ) du
LEFT JOIN
        table2 unit
ON      (userID, question, counter) IN
        (
        SELECT  du.userID, 'Unit', MAX(counter)
        FROM    table2 td
        WHERE   userID = du.userID
                AND question = 'Unit'
        )
LEFT JOIN
        table2 demo
ON      (userID, question, counter) IN
        (
        SELECT  du.userID, 'Demo', MAX(counter)
        FROM    table2 td
        WHERE   userID = du.userID
                AND question = 'Demo'
        )
```

Having an index on `table2 (userID, question, counter)` will greatly improve this query.

Since you mentioned `SQL Server 2005`, the following will be easier and more efficient:

```
SELECT  du.userID,
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 answer
        FROM    table2 ti
        WHERE   ti.user = du.userID
                AND ti.question = 'Unit'
        ORDER BY
                counter DESC
        ) AS unit_answer,
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 answer
        FROM    table2 ti
        WHERE   ti.user = du.userID
                AND ti.question = 'Demo'
        ORDER BY
                counter DESC
        ) AS demo_answer
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT userID
        WHERE   date > '1/1/2009'
        FROM    table1
        ) du
```

To aggregate:

```
SELECT  answer, COUNT(*)
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT userID
        FROM    table1
        WHERE   date > '1/1/2009'
        ) du
JOIN    table2 t2
ON      t2.userID = du.userID
        AND t2.question = 'Unit'
GROUP BY
        answer
```

Comment: When I try to run this, I get an error: Invalid column name 'maxcnt'.
I'm working in sql server management studio. Also, I need the max count for each "userID and Question", not the overall max count of the whole table. Can it be done?

Comment: Thanks, but still a problem.  I changed the top line to select * so I could see all data being returned.  All records in all columns except the userID column is null.  No data!  There should be some.

Comment: You are talking about the last query with TOP 1's?

Comment: I can't believe it.  I think the second one is working for me.  I'll have to study it.  Thanks Quassinoi.

Comment: You're welcome, but accept the answer if it fits you so that I can finally get my 10K. Not that I care much, but, you know... :)

Comment: I will mark it accepted, but I have one more question first.  This query is great, but can it summarize?  Can you add count and group by?  For example, for Unit = A, there are 23 Demos = x and 46 demos = y and for Unit = B, there are 60 Demos = x and 34 Demos = y, etc.

Comment: "23 demos = x" with same counter values?

Comment: No. For all records that are Unit = A, there are 23 Demos that equal x and 46 demos that equal y.  For all records that are unit = B, there are 60 Demos that equal x and 34 Demos that equal y.